# Finding $\frac{DK}{DI}$

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC,$ where $AB = 8, AC = 7,$ and $BC = 10,$ $I$ is the incenter. If $AI$ intersects $BC$ at $K$ and the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $D,$ find $\frac{DK}{DI}.$

---

I first drew a diagram, but I was unsure where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: Attach the diagram to the question.

Comment: Done, sorry for neglecting that.

Comment: I think it would be useful to draw the line $AI$ as well.

Comment: So far, I've found that $IK = \frac{3\sqrt{55}}{5}$ using Heron's Formula and the formula for an inradius. Is there a good way to find $DK$ though?

Comment: You are done if you can compute $AK$.

Comment: How would computing $AK$ help, and how would I go about computing it?

Comment: Sorry, I know how to compute AK now, but how would that help?

Comment: Use the power of a point.

Comment: But what's $BK$ and $CK?$

Comment: Angle bisector theorem.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

I have doubts that you correctly compute the result, since the value $IK$ given in comments is incorrect. The correct result is:
$$\frac{DK}{DI}=\frac23.
$$
The details are given below.

> Let $x,y,z$ being the distances from the vertices $A,B,C$ to the tangent points of the incircle. From the equations $x+y=c, y+z=a, z+x=b$ one obtains $x=\frac{b+c-a}2=s-a$, where $s$ is the semiperimeter. Then:
> $$AI=\sqrt{x^2+r^2}=\sqrt{(s-a)^2+\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}s}=\sqrt {\frac {bc (s-a)}{s}}=2\sqrt{\frac{14}5}.$$
> The angle bisector length [is](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Angle_Bisector):
> $$AK=\sqrt{bc\left[1-\left(\frac  a{b+c}\right)^2\right]}=\frac {\sqrt{4bc (s-a)s}}{b+c}=\frac{10}3\sqrt{\frac{14}5}.$$
> By the power of point $K$ and angle bisector theorem:$$\color {red}{DK}=\frac{BK\cdot KC}{AK}=\frac{a^2\frac{bc}{(b+c)^2}}{AK}=\frac{a^2}{b+c}  \sqrt {\frac{bc}{4 (s-a)s}}=\frac83\sqrt{\frac{14}5},$$
> so that:
> $$\color {red}{DI}=DK+AK-AI=4\sqrt{\frac{14}5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that,  $ID=DB=DC$.

Now, notice that,  $\triangle AKB\sim \triangle ACD$ and hence $\frac{AD}{CD}=\frac{AB}{KB}$. Putting in $ID=CD$ will give the value of $ID$ and thereafter $DK$